# Stack Overflow Careers job link / post tags mess and overlap issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs, design

The tags on the "[Sr. Software Developer/Web Application Developer](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/93942/sr-software-developer-web-application-developer-mediaradar)" job post are a big mess. They are clubbed together and formed a big long link of tags. It also overflows on the share sidebar to its right.

Here is the screenshot of it:

> [image]

I can reproduce this in the following browsers:

Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit))

Firefox (Version 39.0)

Safari (Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12))

On my MacBook Pro (Retina, Late 2013; OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2)

Comment: I would suspect that this is user error as opposed to a bug. Maybe there should be a maximum tag length but it looks as though someone fat fingered a copy and paste and didn't realise.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards but copy n paste from where?

Comment: Their internal job description? Who knows; no one wrote that out and thought it looked good though :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks! We've gone ahead and cleaned the post up and will work with the client on how to best use tags.

Comment: It's gone!! Thanks for fixing it... in no time

Comment: Could you please add [status-completed] tag to my post.  It's no more a open bug.